# cfdocument processing is very slow for text with RTL (Right To Left) direction

Tags: coldfusion, itext, coldfusion-9, right-to-left

In my application an event gateway is used to generate PDF files (more than 100 000) for Arabic texts and English text. During this process we noticed that it is taking very long time to generate Arabic PDF files compared to English one. Say, when English PDF took few seconds Arabic PDF took few minutes.

Have any one came across the same issue ever ? I feel that when text direction is changed (from LTR to RTL) it might be taking some more time time to generate. Any thoughts or suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Also, we noticed that generating PDF for RTL texts is comparatively faster in CF16 than CF9. But, at the moment, our client dont want to upgrade to CF16 from the existing CF9.

Comment: Which version of iText? Any pivotal code you can share?

Comment: iText 2.1.0 (by lowagie.com)

Comment: iText version 2.1.0 was released in March 2008, more than 10 years ago. That version is no longer supported by iText Software. In recent years there have been many improvements for RTL languages. You are also missing out on the advanced typographic features that aren't in iText Core but in the pdfCalligraph add-on. Sorry if it sounds like a pitch but the version of iText you installed in Coldfusion is really, really ancient.

Comment: Can you please say which version on wards have major improvements for RTL languages?.

Comment: I know this is very outside of the question asked, but it always makes me cringe when I hear someone still being stuck on CF9. I know you say the client doesn't want to upgrade, but there have been _MANY_ improvements in ColdFusion since CF9, not to mention the JVM upgrades. Plus, CF9 reached end-of-life 4 years ago. If they don't want to pay Adobe's expense, there's always Lucee. But upgrading would make both your life and their lives _MUCH_ easier, even if you only found a way to upgrade to just CF10.

Comment: Also, know that ColdFusion 2018 is now available, with performance and security improvements on top of the 2016 version. You'll never get any speed improvements on CF 9 as the version of Java it supports has also been sunset. I would suggest you do a cost-benefit analysis of moving to CF 2018 vs. trying to keep CF 9 plugging along. Is it going to cost more to stay on 9 with its slower performance and limited feature set than to upgrade?

Comment: fwiw, CF2016+ still use iText 2.1.0, so as others mentioned it's likely the CF and JVM updates that are the source of the performance improvements.

Comment: RE @AdrianJ.Moreno's point: That cost benefit analysis should probably include the likely cost of a breach. With technology as old as CF9, I would guess that the chances of someone exploiting your site are significantly higher than normal.

Comment: A good reference is https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=53&product_id=8739&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=86&sha=65513b80fd501bdee5446bd56283132d60129ef7  < Note that 3 of the 5 highest severity issues relate directly to CF9. And all 5 include it.